# How to access NoteProperties on the InputObject to a remoting session

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I'm having difficulty accessing `PSObject`s with NoteProperties defined, that are being passed through to a remote session via `Invoke-Command`.  The reason I am constructing an object for this purpose is that I need access to two separate pieces of information in the remote session, but PowerShell only provides for a single `InputObject`.

My code looks something like this:

```
$sessionInput = new-object -TypeName System.Object
$sessionInput | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name NoteProperty1 -Value @("some", "value")
$sessionInput | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name NoteProperty2 -Value @("some", "other", "value)
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName my-computer -Credential (Get-Credential)
Invoke-Command -Session $session -InputObject $sessionInput {
    $input #1
    $input | Get-Member #2
    $input.NoteProperty1 #3
    $input.NoteProperty1 | Get-Member #4
}
```

I get the following output for each of the numbered lines above.

### 1. `$input`

So, first of all I tried my usual technique of dumping the variable to the console, which confirmed that the properties were passed through with the expected value:

```
NoteProperty1      : {some, value}
NoteProperty2      : {some, other, value}
PSComputerName     : my-computer
RunspaceId         : d1f35c8b-f631-4caa-bae0-f7c0066bbd55
PSShowComputerName : True
```

### 2. `$input | Get-Member`

This generated slightly more information than the previous attempt:

```
   TypeName: Deserialized.System.Object

WARNING: column "PSComputerName" does not fit into the display and was removed.

Name          MemberType   Definition                                                                                       
----          ----------   ----------                                                                                       
Equals        Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                                   
GetHashCode   Method       int GetHashCode()                                                                                
GetType       Method       type GetType()                                                                                   
ToString      Method       string ToString(), string ToString(string format, System.IFormatProvider formatProvider)         
NoteProperty1 NoteProperty Deserialized.System.String[] NoteProperty1=some val...
NoteProperty2 NoteProperty Deserialized.System.String[] NoteProperty2=some oth...
```

Note that the last two lines clearly show the NoteProperty is present on the object received by the remote session.  All those mentions of `Deserialized` are starting to pique my interest...

### 3. `$input.NoteProperty1`

Having had some luck with the first two, I started trying to inspect `NoteProperty1` itself.  However, the value of this property appears to be null; nothing is written to the console using the line above, `$input.NoteProperty1 -eq $null` returns True.

### 4. `$input.NoteProperty1 | Get-Member`

So, last of all, I tried to inspect the `NoteProperty1` value directly via `Get-Member`, which failed miserably with the message "No object has been specified to the get-member cmdlet.", which is consistent with a null object being passed to Get-Member.

### Help!

So, I'm completely at a loss now: this Schrödinger property both exists and does not; both has the expected value, and has no value.  I think I can write this in a slightly different way that will eliminate the need for the NoteProperties, but I would love to know what's going on here!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select Object for the win! :)

```
$SessionInput = New-Object -TypeName System.Object
$SessionInput | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name NoteProperty1 -Value @("some", "value")
$SessionInput | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name NoteProperty2 -Value @("some", "other", "value")
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName 127.0.0.1
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -InputObject $SessionInput {
    [array]$NoteProperty1 = $Input | Select -Expand NoteProperty1
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $NoteProperty1.Count; $i ++)
    {
        Write-Host -ForeGroundColor "Magenta" $i
        $NoteProperty1[$i]
    }
}
```

For String variables you still need to expand the string in the select statement like this:

```
$SessionInput = New-Object -TypeName System.Object
$SessionInput | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name NoteProperty1 -Value "SomeValue"
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName 127.0.0.1
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -InputObject $SessionInput {
    $NoteProperty1 = $Input | Select -Expand NoteProperty1
    $NoteProperty1
}
```

Comment: Follow-up question: why doesn't this technique work for [string] NoteProperties? It comes back as [string]::Empty.

Comment: Something to remember, `$input` is an Enumeration of the collection of input objects, NOT the object itself.  That is why #3 and #4 did not work.