# Does Select-Object modify the input?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

Following up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775272/how-to-access-noteproperties-on-the-inputobject-to-a-remoting-session), it seems like Select-Object sets its input to null as part of its processing. This seems wrong to me.  Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
$sessionInput = new-object -TypeName System.Object
$sessionInput | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Foo -Value $foo
$sessionInput | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Bar -Value $bar
Invoke-Command -Session $session -InputObject $sessionInput {
    $foo = $input | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Foo
    $bar = $input | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Bar

    # Expected: $foo, $bar inside the session = $foo, $bar outside the session
}
```

What actually happens is that only `$foo` has its expected value, and `$bar` is always `$null`.  After a little investigation, it turns out that `$input` is set to `$null` after the first `Select-Object` runs.  As an example, inserting `$input | Get-Member` in between the two `Select-Object` lines throws an error stating that "No object has been specified to the get-member cmdlet."

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of $input in this instance is `` [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineReader`1+GetReadEnumerator>d__0[[System.Object]]] ``.  Doing `$inputParameters = $input | Select-Object` to read the object out of the pipeline and stash it away has the desired effect: `$inputParameters` has type `PSCustomObject` and can be poked further multiple times by calls to `Select-Object`.

Comment: Also, Select-Object creates new objects, and copies over the values of the properties you ask for.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? specifying $SomeVar = $Input and then calling that instead?

```
$sessionInput = new-object -TypeName System.Object
$sessionInput | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Foo -Value $foo
$sessionInput | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Bar -Value $bar
Invoke-Command -Session $session -InputObject $sessionInput {
    $TempInput = $input
    $foo = $TempInput | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Foo
    $bar = $TempInput | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Bar

    # Expected: $foo, $bar inside the session = $foo, $bar outside the session
}
```